# One-to-one correspondance shows that infinity can get bigger?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Brian Shmidt, an Australian fellow, and Nobel Prize winner, [said](http://www.abc.net.au/tv/qanda/txt/s4069393.htm) responding to the question “
how can something as infinitely large 
as the universe actually get bigger?
”

> “
>   So,  ultimately,  we're  expanding  into 
>   the  future  but  think  of  it  this  way:  in 
>   school  you  would  have  done  this  little 
>   experiment in math where you will put 
>   a ray starting at zero and it will go out 
>   one,  two,  three  and  off  to  infinity.  You 
>   put  a  little  arrow,  it  goes  off  forever. 
>   So  I  can  multiply  that  by  two.  So  zero 
>   stays at zero, one goes to two, two goes 
>   to four, four goes to eight and you can 
>   do  that  for  any  number  you  want  all 
>   the way up to infinity. And that's sort of 
>   what  the  universe  is  doing.  Infinity  is 
>   just  getting  bigger  and  we’re  allowed 
>   to   do   that   in   mathematics.   That’s 
>   what’s so cool about math
>   .”

In other means, he did a one-to-one correspondance

$\begin{matrix}
0\to&1\to&2\to&3\to&4\to\ldots\\
\rlap\uparrow\downarrow & \rlap\uparrow\downarrow & \rlap\uparrow\downarrow & \rlap\uparrow\downarrow & \cdots \\
0\to&2\to&4\to&6\to&8\to\ldots\end{matrix}$

However these sequences have the same cardinality (hence same "size"), so they aren't examples of "infinity getting bigger". But I'm doubtful... Can anyone confirm?

Comment: That doesn't look at all like what he is dong. You have $n$ going to $n^2$. But he's talking about $n\to 2n$, first of all, and second of all, he's not really talking about cardinality, it doesn't appear, but talking about how an infinite universe can expand.

Comment: My interpretation, as a non-physics person: If there were no forces at all amongst particles to keep them together, two particles distance $d$ apart will, after time $t$, be $\alpha(t)d$ apart. The addition of particle interactions keeps the distances from expanding when the particles are close enough that forces have effect, but the general "average" expansion between particles is this multiple $\alpha(t)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, changed that to $n\longrightarrow2n$ but he was trying to state how something infinitely big can get bigger, i.e. how infinity can become bigger, it seems far probable that he was talking about cardinaity, as it seems.

Comment: But he isn't talking about "bigger" in terms of cardinality, he was talking about expansion. There is a reason he is talking about rays, and not natural numbers. You are misinterpreting him in terms of the mathematical concept of cardinality, but he's talking about things getting bigger in a different sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schmidt picked a wrong example because it doesn't illustrate what he meant to say.

A good example would be a map that sends $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Z$ surjectively, for instance

$$f(n) = \left\{ \begin {array} {ll}
k, && n=2k \\
-k, && n=2k-1
\end{array} \right. .$$

Despite being infinite, $\Bbb N$ can "expand" and cover $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: However they have the same cardinality and aren't getting "bigger". But thanks for answering my question, my doubt is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of "expansion" is not the same as the notion of "getting bigger" in terms of cardinality.

Rather, the universe "expands" in the way that a balloon expands - except, of course, that a balloon is "finite" (or "compact.")

He's saying that two points $v,w$ in space are actually farther apart as time passes. Presumably, the time it takes to double the size of a distance is huge, and the expansion is fairly slow in our measure of time. Also, presumably, the forces amongst particles keep nearby particles together even as space expands, but the expansion causes far-apart objects with little gravitational or other forces between them, on average, to increase their distances, much as if you drew two dots on a ballon and then inflated the balloon.

Comment: I like to think of it as there being a Universal Standards Organization much like our ISO, and they are constantly redefining the length of their standard meterstick.

Comment: Same notion as shown in Gravitation by Wheeler & co. I perfectly understand that, and I agree with it; However I was talking about what Brian Shmidt was saying and whether it makes sense.

Comment: Same notion as shown in the famous [Gravitation by Wheeler & co](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113593/an-error-in-gravitation-by-misner-thorne-and-wheeler). I perfectly understand that, and I agree with it; However I was talking about what Brian Shmidt was saying and whether it makes sense. Sorry if that was rude

Answer (score 0):

He talks about

$$
\begin{matrix}
0\to & 1\to & 2\to & 3\to & 4\to & \ldots\\
\rlap\uparrow\downarrow & 
\rlap\uparrow\downarrow & 
\rlap\uparrow\downarrow & 
\rlap\uparrow\downarrow & 
\rlap\uparrow\downarrow & \\
0\to & 2\to & 4\to & 6\to & 8\to &\ldots
\end{matrix}
$$

but probably means

$$
\begin{matrix}
0&\to&1&\to&2&\to&3&\to&4\to&\ldots\\
\rlap\uparrow\downarrow & & 
\rlap\uparrow\downarrow & &
\rlap\uparrow\downarrow & &
\rlap\uparrow\downarrow & & 
\rlap\uparrow\downarrow \\
0\to & 1\to & 2\to & 3\to & 4\to & 5\to & 6\to & 7\to & 8\to&\ldots\end{matrix}
$$
which would correspond to the universal dough rising, be it now finite or infinite.

Comment: OP seems to know that last sentence, he's just applying it inappropriately to a different argument.